# socket connection to my own page on freehosting

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to make my own simple instant message chat in java. I know how to implement it on my localhost using following methods:
server side:

```
new ServerSocket(8080);
```

client side:

```
new Socket("localhost", 8080);
```

this allows me to make my computer server and client as well. Is there (and I know there is) a way to make connection via internet?
Since the localhost is actually an IP address, will the solution of occupation of free hosting work? for example if i will have an ip address "http://freewebhosting.something.com", can I put it instead of parameter "localhost"? No, I'm not so lazy to try it, but there may be more efficient way how to implement it I would like to know how. Thanks for any advices and be aware I'm not very familiar with networking and so.

Comment: You should omit the "http". Just new `Socket("freewebhosting.something.com", 8080)`.

Comment: of course since "localhost" does not contain "http://" string, I forgot to edit it, thanks anyway, but are you sure it will work?

Comment: Yes it will work. Of course much more code around it is needed. I have created a small UDP tool. It contains both server and client code. So you may start two instances of it and use it to chat to each other. See https://github.com/rasenderhase/nikem_public/releases/latest

Comment: thanks so much, but I wonder if it will not be on localhost, but on server (i don't know where), will there be need for server to be started first?

Comment: Yes you must write a server in Java and start it on the server of your hosting provider. It's not easy to find providers that allow to start java programs on the server. Usually you have to rent a linux root server. Then you have to install java on it to run your program. Have fun! (Sorry, I didn't... my root server got hacked and abused as a spambot)

Comment: hmmm.. of course it was a stupid question if server needs to be started as first, but i was unable to edit my comment :P maybe i should take a look on peer to peer implementation.

Comment: No worries Pink. There are no stupid questions. Only stupid answers... :-) Is the chat a commercial project or just for fun?

Comment: just fun, but I just found openshift - this is the place where i will try to run my server :)